# Best approach to communicate my library service with my app

Tags: kotlin, interface

I have a library in my project that is using a service to listen for notifications. That I want to do is when the notification arrive, notify the app from the library that is handle the notification.

I don't know how to notice the app from the library. I'm trying doing a interface, but I can't initialize the interface and not sure if this is a good approach.

This is that I'm trying to do:

In App class:

```
val notification = object: PushNotificationInterface {
            override fun listenForPush(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
             //Do something
            }
        }
```

Interface:

```
interface PushNotificationInterface {

    fun listenForPush(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage)

}
```

Library class:

```
class HMSPushMessagingService: HmsMessageService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        PushToken.token = token
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        //This line give an error in PushNotificationInterface(remoteMessage)
        interfaceTest(listenerInterface = PushNotificationInterface(remoteMessage), remoteMessage = remoteMessage)
    }

    private fun interfaceTest(listenerInterface: PushNotificationInterface, remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
            listenerInterface.listenForPush(remoteMessage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an approach using StateFlow

```
class HMSPushMessagingService: HmsMessageService() {

    companion object {
        val messages = MutableStateFlow<RemoteMessage?>(null)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        messages.value = remoteMessage
    }
}
```

StateFlow is a SharedFlow so you can collect it from many places in your app

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            HMSPushMessagingService.messages.collect {
                val remoteMessage = it
                // do something
            }
        }
        // or
        HMSPushMessagingService.messages.onEach {
            // do something
        }.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
    }
}
```

read more about StateFlow [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow)

Comment: i have this error in the method of the MainActivity Type mismatch.
Required:
FlowCollector<RemoteMessage?>
Found:
(Nothing) → Unit

Comment: try the second way. if you still have errors, show me your code